# Sending data to BLE device from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-bluetooth

I am working on an iPhone app that is to control some features of a car from an iPhone. Features include locking and unlocking of car doors, opening the trunk, and producing an alarm sound. I'm using the core Bluetooth framework so I can connect my phone to BLE device.

The actual phenomenon is to send 2 different voltage levels: 0 and 1. So doors are opened at 1 and closed at 0. How can I do this through code, or is there any other way?

Comment: You have the BLE specifications of the peripheral you are trying to control?  Then the Core Bluetooth [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TemperatureSensor/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012194-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) from Apple should help.

Answer (score 0):

Look for `writeValue:forCharacteristic:type` in CoreBluetooth.framework.